# How long should a judo belt be?

Tags: judo, belt, uniform

How long should a judo belt be? Taekwondo and Karate belts for example are often quite long, with both ends dangling below the skirt of the gi, but judo belts are often worn a lot shorter. Is there a standard?

| Taekwondo | Judo |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 2):

According to IJF regulations:

> Belt (see picture 13)
>
> - The thickness must be between 4 and 5mm.
> - The tips starting from the central knot must have a length between 20 and 30
>   cm.
> - The belt must not be made of a stiff and/or slipping material and the knot must
>   be correctly and tightly made.
>
> [image]

- [IJF Judogi rules - 09.03.2022](https://www.ijf.org/documents)

To meet regulations, Mizuno recommends buying a belt of the following length relative to your waist circumference:

> SIZE OF BELTS
>
> To choose the right size for your judo belt, there is a formula. **Take your waist, multiply it by two and add 95 cm.** If you are between two sizes, take the one above. This formula takes into account the standard of the International Judo Federation which says that it is necessary to let the belt exceed 20 to 30 cm from the knot. Example of a judoka with a waist of 73 cm: (73 x 2) + 95 = 241 cm. We recommend a size 2.5 judo belt.